# Pivot, dynamic data source

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot chart which currently has the data source referring to my table.

Every week I run my code and a new row of data is appended to the bottom of my table.

The pivot does pick up this new data every week as it refers to the table, however, I want to take one less week each week So I have a years worth of data. So I want to include around rows.

Is there anyway to adjust my table to only include the years worth of rows?

Here is my sample data:

```
+----------+------------------+-----------------+
|   week   |      stack       |    overflow     |
+----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 12/20/17 | -142,335,432.00  | -41,641,109.88  |
| 12/27/17 | -105,428,220.20  | -47,448,990.63  |
| 1/3/18   |  -88,520,154.56  | -24,858,774.97  |
| 1/10/18  |  -42,033,431.10  |  14,573,779.35  |
| 1/17/18  |  -66,101,748.16  |  -8,670,735.22  |
| 1/24/18  |  -75,871,649.12  | -18,000,154.21  |
| 1/31/18  |  -77,027,686.63  | -11,784,198.64  |
| 2/7/18   |  -96,720,126.71  | -52,219,288.98  |
| 2/14/18  | -119,118,554.60  | -34,743,350.28  |
| 2/21/18  | -116,529,554.70  | -20,774,072.93  |
| 2/28/18  |  -86,871,998.53  | -25,993,521.20  |
| 3/7/18   |  -90,351,387.27  | -21,259,727.05  |
| 3/14/18  |  -77,968,076.28  | -51,609,924.29  |
| 3/21/18  | -120,805,352.60  | -40,338,490.97  |
| 3/28/18  |  -92,247,583.62  | -14,525,648.04  |
| 4/4/18   |  -70,821,451.36  | -35,866,864.46  |
| 4/11/18  |  -82,694,486.66  | -59,009,729.82  |
| 4/18/18  |  -79,034,094.39  | -64,231,312.42  |
| 4/25/18  |  -63,415,815.16  | -28,612,265.37  |
| 5/2/18   |  -80,372,191.96  | -53,375,611.61  |
| 5/9/18   |  -72,619,415.73  | -50,642,469.19  |
| 5/16/18  | -109,654,240.70  | -45,762,784.43  |
| 5/23/18  | -100,407,366.50  | -39,577,966.11  |
| 5/30/18  | -105,794,095.80  | -65,071,199.59  |
| 6/6/18   |  -83,630,201.98  | -60,981,969.88  |
| 6/13/18  | -104,644,821.50  | -63,754,760.71  |
| 6/20/18  |  -75,229,424.33  | -55,803,681.24  |
| 6/27/18  |  -65,237,135.62  | -54,693,832.65  |
| 7/4/18   |  -60,025,672.33  | -44,367,918.60  |
| 7/11/18  |  -30,172,175.09  | -28,392,163.28  |
| 7/18/18  |  -20,687,864.39  |  24,300,285.63  |
| 7/25/18  |  -40,476,447.03  |   4,850,881.09  |
| 8/1/18   |  -31,211,625.05  | -67,887,918.30  |
| 8/8/18   |  -29,736,938.87  | -32,905,703.80  |
| 8/15/18  |  -74,934,647.91  | -65,611,884.73  |
| 8/22/18  |  -25,220,747.20  |  -7,019,746.86  |
| 8/29/18  |  -24,608,552.13  |  -8,065,633.97  |
| 9/5/18   |  -30,119,599.95  | -26,225,633.08  |
| 9/12/18  |  -29,836,379.12  | -10,045,560.95  |
| 9/19/18  |  -61,281,567.61  | -58,427,878.27  |
| 9/26/18  |  -47,418,209.59  | -33,451,409.22  |
| 10/3/18  |  -41,321,336.46  | -25,112,764.44  |
| 10/10/18 |   -1,241,932.51  |  21,814,274.35  |
| 10/17/18 |  -19,791,273.66  | -12,199,449.75  |
| 10/24/18 |  -20,501,406.84  |   1,225,387.11  |
| 10/31/18 |  -64,116,464.30  |  -5,308,628.21  |
| 11/7/18  |  -83,657,672.02  | -19,922,992.91  |
| 11/14/18 | -112,704,007.53  | -32,939,535.69  |
| 11/21/18 |  -71,969,954.54  | -51,335,709.79  |
| 11/28/18 |  -79,668,484.56  | -67,887,918.30  |
| 12/5/18  |  -44,134,343.99  | -32,905,703.80  |
| 12/12/18 |  -71,700,079.84  | -65,611,884.73  |
| 12/19/18 |  -82,238,011.30  | -74,725,620.20  |
| 12/26/18 |  -59,385,932.41  | -54,947,256.94  |
| 1/2/19   |  -42,717,830.26  | -31,110,199.14  |
| 1/9/19   |  -11,029,444.63  |   7,309,440.90  |
+----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the source range for the pivot will be tricky as Excel does not allow non-contiguous cells to be used in pivot tables. Instead you can create the pivot by selecting entire column to account for all future entries. 
Then the pivot can be manipulated to show a changing range as shown in the code below.
Hope that works for you.

**EDIT**

The code is updated below to include 50(can be changed) from the bottom.

```
Sub MovingPivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dtTop As Date
    Dim i As Integer, n As Long

    Const NumWeeks = 50 'Change this to set weeks range


    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Set reference to your worksheet here

    'reset the pivot filters
    ws.PivotTables("Table1").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
    'remove blank values
    ws.PivotTables("Table1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False


    'find the date entry in 50 places from bottom.
    i = 0
    For n = ws.PivotTables("Table1").RowRange.Count To 1 Step -1
        If i = NumWeeks Then
            dtTop = ws.PivotTables("Table1").RowRange.Cells(n).Value
            Exit For
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next n

    ws.PivotTables("Table1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlAfterOrEqualTo, Value1:=Format(dtTop, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: okay i like the idea, so my data source should be all the columns, in this case X:AH . And where in this code can I alter it to get  from the last row up 50 rows?

Comment: yes the data source should be the entire column (assuming you heading row is on row 1). See updated code above to set 50 weeks from bottom.

Comment: Trying to do it a second time, this time the data source is not in a table, it is actually another sheet. I get `unable to get the rowrange property of the PivotTable class` on line `For n = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("scencount").RowRange.Count To 1 Step -1`

Comment: Hansraj you there?

Comment: I have updated the code. Activesheet only works on the currently active sheet. if your pivot is in another sheet use that sheet reference. in the line set ws = Activesheet, replace with set ws = thisworkbook.worksheets("nameof yoursheet")

Comment: I should clarify, the pivot is on the same sheet as my original, the data source is on a different page, should that matter?

Comment: That should not matter. make sure that the pivot table name is updated in your code. In my code it is assumed as "Table1". you can set the name of a pivot table using Analyze Menu (under the pivot table tools ribbon"), to the left of the ribbon there will be a text box to update the name"

Comment: That should not matter. make sure that the pivot table name is updated in your code. In my code it is assumed as Table1. you can set the name of a pivot table using Analyze Menu (under the pivot table tools ribbon"), to the left of the ribbon there will be a text box to update the name"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using a Pivot Chart, you can use the time line slicer to include/exclude data. You'll need to adjust the time line or filter manually after the data has refreshed. Or write VBA to set the filters.

A non-vba version that does not require slicers can also be achieved with a standard chart (not a pivot chart). Create named ranges with Offset functions that grab just the rows of data that you are interested in, then plug these range names into the standard chart. When new data is added to the table, the named ranges that feed the standard chart will also be updated.

If you need a step by step, take a look at https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicLast12.html